# How to count overlaps between multiple categories in R

Tags: r, data.table, overlap, iranges

I have a data frame of start time, end time  in UNIX time stamp and category, as below:

[image]

I want to find the overlaps of one  category say "a" among  other categories "b" & "c" and same for other categories. I want to find  how many number of categories overlapped how many times e.g. 2 categories overlapped 3 times and 3 categories overlapped 5 number of time. And also the average of duration they overlapped for as shown below.

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Maybe have a look at `?data.table::foverlaps`

Comment: Please provide a minimal and reproducible example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Floo0 : I tried doing this through creating if and else condition on start and end for two categories at a time and I also tried IRanges/Genomic Ranges but I am not able to get the result since there are too many categories. Thanks for suggesting "foverlaps" but again it takes two categories at a time and it will take huge time for all categories taken one by one on 4 months data.

Comment: @Alex: I do not have a reproducible example for this.

Comment: Can't you create one?